# peer to peer System with remote method invocation(rmi)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rmi, distributed-system

How would you incorporate distributed algorithms such as vector timestamps, a leader election algorithm into a peer to peer system created using RMI? I have to come up with a peer to peer system that utilizes distributed algorithms. I would really appreciate if any one could give me some ideas.

Cheers

Comment: RMI is a client-server system.